Odd use of comma
Follow up from my recent question:

また、キラ・ヤマトはスーパーコーディネイターとして数多の犠牲の上に生み出された自身の出自と重ね「望む力を全て得ようと遺伝子にまで手を伸ばしてきたコーディネイターの世界の究極」である、漫画『THE EDGE』内では「遺伝子で職業が決まるなら、より職業の適性の高い優れた人間を狙って製造する方向へと加速する」＝「人間を工業製品やパーツ同等として扱う様になる」「より社会的に優遇される職（医者や政治家など）への適性をコーディネイトする様になる」と危惧し、「未来を作るのは運命（遺伝子の適性）じゃない」「夢（願い・希望・欲望）を抱けないのは嫌だ」と反感を示した。

This sentence appears to be a run-on sentence to me. I found the use of the comma after ...コーディネイターの世界の究極」である is odd. I think it should be a period instead because the protagonist of the manga THE EDGE is not キラ・ヤマト. Perhaps it is a typo?

No, this is not a typo nor a run-on sentence. That 究極」である connects to と危惧し. The quotative と before 危惧 is applied to two long statements he made in two different scenes.

キラ・ヤマトはXである(と)、漫画『THE EDGE』内ではYと危惧し、…
Kira Yamato feared "X", and in the manga THE EDGE, (he feared) "Y".

Where:

X: (デスティニープランは)「望む力を全て得ようと遺伝子にまで手を伸ばしてきたコーディネイターの世界の究極」である
Y: 「遺伝子で職業が決まるなら、より職業の適性の高い優れた人間を狙って製造する方向へと加速する」＝「人間を工業製品やパーツ同等として扱う様になる」「より社会的に優遇される職（医者や政治家など）への適性をコーディネイトする様になる」

Overall, this sentence has three main verbs:

キラ・ヤマトは[デスティニープランを]自身の出自と重ね、X(と)、(漫画内では)Yと危惧し、Zと反感を示した。
Kira Yamato compared Destiny Plan to his own origins, feared saying X and, in the manga, (saying) Y, and showed resentment saying Z.

In my opinion, a sentence this long and difficult to read should be called poor writing rather than an intellectual sentence. Unfortunately, some people prefer to write such sentences.
